# can a malware debug a debugging tool?

Tags: debugging

can a malware debug a debugger like IDA, for example, look for an API that is used for debugging.

and maybe makes it crash or change some values printed to the person using it.

for tools that are widely used I guess it could be ways that malware can use to throw off the person who's debugging.

Comment: Yes, it's a common technique used by malware authors. On a related note, some malware even avoids running if your language is set to Russian. https://it.slashdot.org/story/21/07/07/2355258/code-in-huge-ransomware-attack-written-to-avoid-computers-that-use-russian-says-new-report

Comment: yes, but can the malware debug the debugger as it's debugging the malware at the same time.like loading some DLL that manipulates the memory used by the debugger while it's debugging the malware

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down

Comment: even if the malware is running on the kernel level?